# Google Maps API problem - initMap()

Tags: google-maps

I do custom wordpress temple site with google maps script, and php code. I have problem with loading of it, they do not always work, sometimes i must refreshing site ten times until it starts to work.

If they do not work, I get an error

`"initMap is not a function"`

**Code of my temple site:**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Mapy */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<style>
    #colophon{
        display: none;
    }
    .page-template {
        background-color: black!important;
    }
    .gm-style-iw {
        height: 165px!important;
        width: 300px!important;
    }
</style>

<section style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom:0px;">
    <div id="map" class="no-transition"></div>
    <div class="legend">
        <ul>
            <li>Wielki format</li>
            <li>Citylight</li>
            <li>Backlight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

<?php 

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-map-script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    $storeData = [];
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    foreach ($loop->posts as $post){
        $storeData[] = [
            'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
            'url' => get_permalink(),
            'num'   => get_field('numer_katalogowy'),
            'lat'   => get_field('gps_dlugosc'),
            'long'  => get_field('szerokosc_gps'),
            'surface'  => get_field('powierzchnia'),
            'height'  => get_field('dlugosc'),
            'width'  => get_field('szerokosc'),
            'light'  => get_field('oswietlenie'),
        ];
    }
    wp_localize_script('my-map-script', 'storeData', $storeData);
?>


<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAg-GBNbwLWCxiN-UI-0COkr1bgAKpXjQU&callback=initMap"></script>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Code of my js file:**

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
    var poznan = {lat: 52.402684, lng: 16.9213905};
    var j = storeData.length;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 200
    });
    var marker, i;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: poznan,
      }
    );

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(storeData[i].lat, storeData[i].long),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(
                    '<div class="marker-window-content">' +
                        '<h3>' + storeData[i].title + '</h3>' +
                        '<span>' + storeData[i].num + '</span>' +
                        '<p>' + 'Wysokość: ' + storeData[i].height + ' m'+ '</p>' +
                        '<p>' + 'Szerokość: ' + storeData[i].width + ' m'+ '</p>' +
                        '<p>' + 'Powierzchnia: ' + storeData[i].surface + ' m2'+ '</p>' +
                        '<p>' + 'Oświetlenie: ' + storeData[i].light + '</p>' +
                        '<a href="'+ storeData[i].url + '">' + 'Przejdź do powierzchni' + '</a>' +
                    '</div>'


                );
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

I think the problem can be in script order, but i don't know how to resolve it.
Adress of site where is problem:

[My site](http://new.biggroup.pl/mapa-powierzchni/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the Google Maps script URL is the culprit:

```
&callback=initMap
```

It means that when the script is loaded it will attempt to run the `initMap()` function, but you're enqueueing your script that contains the function in the footer, after the Google Maps `<script>` tag, which you're outputting in the middle of the page. This means that your script won't be loaded before Google Maps attempts to run `initMap()`.

You should enqueue the Google Maps script using `wp_enqueue_script()`, with your custom script as a dependency, to make sure they load in the right order.

So remove the `<script>` tag and add:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'google-maps', 
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAg-GBNbwLWCxiN-UI-0COkr1bgAKpXjQU&callback=initMap',
    [ 'my-map-script' ],
    null,
    true
);
```

This will ensure that the Google Maps script will be loaded after your script, guaranteeing that the `initMap()` function will be available.

Comment: No problem. If it helped you can mark the answer as accepted to help let other users know that your question has an answer.